# Multiple select from a 2-levels category - how?

Tags: selection, multi-selection, hierarchy, tree, accordion

Assumed I need to provide a way to select items from a 2-level hierarchy. The simplest way is to have a long list of sets of checkboxes (each with a name) - that's great for discovery of the variety of items, however scrolling multiple screens up and down is not the best UX in the world.

So which is the best way to:

- Display the hierarchy in a compact way yet to be able to discover the inner items quickly enough
- See the already selected items in one place and being able to deselect them

Comment: Are users expected to select items from all parents or only from a single parent?

Comment: Imagine that the selection system started with the top-level categories visible, and the user could unfold each one to see the individual items. Do you think your users would be able to immediately tell which categories to open up? Or would they need to open up several categories and search through them in order to find the item they're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a drop down list for the parent category and a check list for items from that category.  The limitation here is you can only select items under one parent category at a time.  But if there is to much data then this might be a good option.